# Baucis + Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, baucis

Good day everyone! I have some problems with understanding baucis (https://github.com/wprl/baucis). In middleware section I found that request can have isAuthenticated() method, but I'm not found any information about it in documentation and I got mistakes when called it. I need to realize this method in my code by myself? My code:

```
var citySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});

mongoose.model('City', citySchema);

var citiesController = baucis.rest('City');

citiesController.request(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next();
  return res.send(401);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your question.

That is non-runnable example code.  The [passport](https://npmjs.org/package/passport) middleware module adds the `isAuthenticated` method to request, though with baucis you are free to use [whatever authentication middleware](https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=authentication) you would like.

HTH!

Comment: yep, I found passport framework yesterday. Useful thing!